# SQL logging query works with SELECT but not with INSERT or UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I've written a PHP function to make running and logging SQL queries easier.

It runs the actual query just fine but I'm having trouble with the logging part. 
the "INSERT INTO log..." command works when the value of $query is a SELECT query.

It does not log however if the query is an INSERT or UPDATE query.

here is my code:

```
// generic query sql
    function querySql($query){
        global $conn;
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if(!$result){ 
            $error = $conn->error;
            $log = $conn->query("INSERT INTO log(query,type,status,error) VALUES('$query','Query','Fail','$error')");
            die($conn->error);
        }
        $log = $conn->query("INSERT INTO log(query,type,status) VALUES('$query','Query','Success')");
        return $result;
    }
```

Could someone please advise?

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: Don't know if it will help fix your problem, but you could rewrite that code to look like `if(!$conn->error) { <getting errors and such>; } else { <log as good result>; }`

Comment: tried `if(!$conn->error){...` and even commenting out the entire if error section as a test. Still doesn't log the query.

Answer (score 0):

Posible your $query containing single code caused SQL error. Try the method below

```
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host={Your Host};dbname={Your DB}",'{Your Username}','{Your Password}');
        $statement1 = $con->prepare($query);
        if(!$statement1->execute())
        {
           $query2 = "INSERT INTO log(query,type,status,error) VALUES(?,'Query','Fail',?)";
           $statement2 = $con->prepare($query2);
           $statement->execute(array($query,json_encode($statement1->errorInfo())));
           die(json_encode($statement1->errorInfo()));
        }
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO log(query,type,status) VALUES(?,'Query','Success')";
        $statement2 = $con->prepare($query2);
        $statement2->execute(array($query));
```

You may learn more about **PDO** on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

Comment: The OP would still get FALSE for $result if there was a mysql error.